# What does this Scheme code do?

Tags: scheme, let

Especially why we are using tailr and headr? I am not able to understand.

```scm
(define (foo lst)
  (cond
    ((not (list? lst)) lst)
    ((null? lst) lst)
    (else (let* ((tail (cdr lst))
                 (head (car lst))
                 (tailr (foo tail))
                 (headr (foo head)))
            (append tailr (list headr))))))
```

Comment: Tail, head, tailr, and headr are just intermediate variables.  The whole let* block could be written as `(append (foo (cdr lst)) (list (foo (car lst))))`.

Comment: Is this a homework or exam question?  It's that time of year, and while I don't see it posted online anywhere, I do see that someone entered the code into ideone, as well, at http://ideone.com/fork/hqywYX;  where they'd be able to *see* what it actually does by running it.

Comment: Just run it... it's recursively reversing the list (and works for nested lists, too). `tailr` and `headr` are just local variables.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is equivalent to:

```
(define (reverse-nested lst)
  (cond ((not (pair? lst)) lst)
        (else (reverse (map reverse-nested lst)))))
```